# Restoring MySQL .sql dump not working when trying to local XAMPP MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, xampp, backup, restore

Below is the code I am trying to use restore a .sql dump to a MySQL database on a local XAMPP server. I just can't see what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```
try {
        String dbName = "Database";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "";
        String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql", " --user=" + dbUser, " --password=" + dbPass, " "+dbName, " -e", " source "+s};

        Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
        int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

        System.out.println(processComplete);
        if (processComplete == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully restored);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error restoring");
        }

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException | HeadlessException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't u upload your mysql dump through phpmyadmin.....

Steps:

1) Go to Phpmyadmin
2) Go to Import
3) Select the dump
4) Upload it it database...

As u have already mentioned that u r using Xampp server, u can easuly upload dump through phpmyadmin

Comment: I want to do it programmatically, almost like having a save and load function within the program.